# The simplest way of websocket based on vanilla JS AJAX long polling

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, websocket, long-polling

I prepare the simplest way of AJAX long polling (realtime) in vanilla JavaScript, without any libraries like jQuery...
The code works based on `timestamp` of data.txt read by PHP file `server.php` (that's all).

```
function realtime(timestamp) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', 'server.php' + (typeof timestamp !== 'undefined' ? '?timestamp=' + timestamp : ''), true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = result.content;

            realtime(result.timestamp);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

realtime();
```

Now, I would like to know how to prepare similar example in `websocket` (without any libraries, just clean JS/PHP).

It is possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, if not - no library would exist that offers websocket support. Implementing sockets without a library is a pain, why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @baao I would like to know websocket from primary level, not reinvent wheel:)

Comment: Well, then just read the specifications and documentation on the websocket API, these will give you all the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

Websocket is a different protocol than HTTP (it uses the HTTP upgrade mechanism).
So you'll have to adapt your webserver AND any reverse proxy etc. to handle websocket connections.